# How can I make it so a TextBox will dynamically adjust the input as a currency format?

Tags: vb.net, textbox, keypress

This app I'm designing has a TextBox named txtValue with the properties MaxLength set to 14 and TextAlign set to Right. I want txtValue to only accept currency, and dynamically format the input so the user doesn't need to add commas, only one period.

I managed to make it so txtValue will only accept numbers and one dot in the event txtValue_KeyPress.

txtValue_LostFocus will convert the input into currency format.

Here's my code so far:

```
Private Sub txtValue_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles txtValue.KeyPress

    'Allows only one dot
    If (e.KeyChar.ToString = ".") And (txtValue.Text.Contains(e.KeyChar.ToString)) Then

        e.Handled = True

        Exit Sub

    End If

    'Allows only 0 to 9 and dot (once)
    If (e.KeyChar.ToString < "0" OrElse e.KeyChar.ToString > "9") _
    AndAlso e.KeyChar <> ControlChars.Back _
    AndAlso e.KeyChar.ToString <> "." Then

        e.Handled = True

    End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtValue_LostFocus(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtValue.LostFocus

    txtValue.Text = Format(Val(txtValue.Text), "000,000,000.00")

End Sub
```

I expect the input -q1w23456789012....34 to return the output 123,456,789,012.34, but the actual output after it loses focus is 123,456,789,012.30

This seems like an easy fix, like setting MaxLength to 15, but then if I don't type a period, it'll allow me to type 15 numbers and I only want up to 12 plus 2 after the period.

I expect the input -q1w234....5678 to return the output 1,234.56, but the actual output after it loses focus is 000,000,001,234.56

This seems like a more complex fix, because I don't want to use the LostFocus event to validate what I type. I want the KeyPress event to handle the input and dynamically format what I type.

In this case:

The input 1 would have the output 1.00

The input 123.4 would have the output 123.40

The input 1234.567 would have the output 1,234.56

All of this without needing the LostFocus event, but right now I'm using the LostFocus event because that's all my very limited knowledge allows me to do.

UPDATE

Alright I'm now using the Leave event, but then again I was only using LostFocus as a placeholder because in the end I want the TextBox to adjust what the user types as they type.

Comment: The `GotFocus` and `LostFocus` events are low-level focus events that are tied to the WM_KILLFOCUS and WM_SETFOCUS Windows messages. Instead the `Enter` and `Leave` events should be used for all controls.

From the docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: But what if the user pastes something into the text box? No Key_Press event!

Comment: Which event should I use instead of Key_Press? And would the code I'm using work in the other event or would I need to start over? @Mary

Comment: Getting an answer ready. give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to handle. For details on formating numbers for display try MS docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-numeric-format-strings

```
Private err As New ErrorProvider()
Private d As Decimal 'In case you want to use the value as a number somewhere else
Private Sub TextBox17_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox17.Validating
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(TextBox17.Text, d) Then
        e.Cancel = True
        err.SetError(TextBox17, "This text box must contain a number.")
    Else
        err.Clear()
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox17_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox17.Validated
    TextBox17.Text = d.ToString("C")
End Sub
```

Comment: It's giving me an error, "Method 'txtValue_Validating' cannot handle event 'Validating' because they do not have a compatible signature." Also, is it err.SetError(TextBox1 or err.SetError(TextBox17?

Comment: `Private Sub txtValue_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles txtValue.Validating

    End Sub` is generated stub for this event. Are you sure you have e As CancelEverntArgs as the second argument?

Comment: So sorry, yes s/b TextBox17

Comment: Oh, it auto-completed `e As ConsoleCancelEventArgs`. Maybe that's what's happening since there's no CancelEventArgs on the suggestion list?

Comment: Hummm. What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: Great! If you go the the designer. Select the text box then open the properties window. Click on the lightning bolt icon. This will display a list of events for the text box. Find the Validating event and double click in the blank space. This will produce the event stub in the code window.

Comment: Oh, thanks. There's the problem, in the version I'm using it requires `System.ComponentModel.` before `CancelEventArgs`. Which event should I use instead of Key_Press to allow only numbers and one dot while the user is typing?

Comment: Can't you just `Imports System.ComponentModel` ? You may have to set a reference first.

Comment: I think i didn't express myself clearly, by using `e As System.ComponentModel' it gives me the option to use `CancelEventArgs` so the code you posted is working for me now. :) But it still converts what I typed only after losing focus on txtValue instead of doing that as I type. Which event would you recommend me to use in order to do that?

Comment: Maybe TextChanged. This would cover the user pasting into the text box. But I still think the Validating event is where validation should occur. :-)

Comment: Another though might be the masked edit text box. I never liked them. As a user I don't want to be harassed while I am typing. Afterwards is OK. Just a personal preference and I guess you have requirements.

Comment: It's a bad idea to force the formatting while the user is typing. I would go so far as to say that you should also be removing the currency formatting explicitly on the `Enter` event too. You're actually making life harder for the user. Let's say that the user wants to enter "$1.23". According to you, when they enter the "1", the control should automatically add ".00". How do they now get the ".23" in there?  Just let them type the number they actually want and then format it. Stop trying to be too tricky.

Comment: I've seen apps developed in other languages before that have this kind of dynamic formatting while the user types, and what you described wasn't a problem in those cases. If I typed 123 and left it that way, the output would be 123.00, the .00 would be there by default. If I typed 1.2 instead, the output would be 1.20. Pressing the 3 key then would make the output 1.23. I'm not trying to be tricky, I'm trying to learn the language while also making sure the user isn't going to mistype something into the TextBox that shouldn't be there.